# How to transform string with character codes into quoted form

Tags: bash, scripting, string

I have a string like `New\x20Folder`. Special characters is represented by their codes. I'd like to transform the string into quoted form: `"New Folder"`.

The only available tools are bash and bunch of standard utilities like sed.

The first form is produced by the udev environment variable `ID_FS_LABEL_ENC`. The needed form is consumed by the autofs config file. It expects quoted strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that backslashes themselves are also escaped in your strings (as `\x5c`, presumably), which `udev` seems to do, you should use Bash's [`printf` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf):

```
printf -v translated '"%b"' "$ID_FS_LABEL_ENC"
```

If we try that on your example string:

```
$ ID_FS_LABEL_ENC='New\x20Folder'
$ printf -v translated '"%b"' "$ID_FS_LABEL_ENC"
$ echo "Translated to: '$translated'"
Translated to: '"New Folder"'
```

we get the transformation you wanted.

`printf -v` assigns the result of a standard `printf`-style translation into a variable, and the `%b` format is a Bash extension performing backslash escape sequences. This is not susceptible to any funny business with names containing odd but legitimate characters and doesn't require rewriting the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string=$'New\x20Folder'
```

or

```
string="New\x20Folder"
string="$(echo -e "$string")"
```